# Flexible javascript timer

Tags: javascript, object, timer

I try to do a timer for a trailer on my site which works perfectly. After 140 milliseconds it shows work no 2 which is work 1, after 410 then follows work no 3 which is work 4 and so on.

Now I’d love to put the times each work has to be shown into my "works" object and let js add them for me.

But just as I started with my idea (under "PROBLEMATIC PART") I ran into the first problem. Why everything works fine if I insert the 140 milliseconds as a number into the first time frame but not if I replace it with the var tt_1??

I checked it with an alert and it contains the correct value. So is there anything tricky here the way js calculates the values? What did I wrong? Thanks in advance!

PS.: It is not that it throws any errors but it takes 10 times more time than the foreseen 140 ms

```
var works = { 
  1: { …, tt: 210 },
  2: { …, tt: 190 },
  3: { …, tt: 140 },
  4: { …, tt: 90 }, 
  5: { …, tt: 100 },
  //…
};

// works in trailer
var trailer = [3,1,4,2,…]

//time line trailer PROBLEMATIC PART
var tw_1 = trailer[0];
var tt_1 = works[tw_1]['tt'];   // ->140
alert(tt_1)                     // alerts correctly 140

var timeFrames = {
  **tt_1**: trailer[1],            // works if 140 inserted here but not with tt_1
  410:  trailer[2],
  590:  trailer[3],
}; 
var maxStep = 680;

<!--optional variables end-->

var timer;
var timerPaused = false;
var stepSize = 100;
var currentStep = 0;

var intervalTimer = function() {

  if ( !timerPaused ) { currentStep ++; }
  if ( !!timeFrames[currentStep] ) {
    //do something each timer step  
}
  if ( currentStep >= maxStep ) {
    //do something at the end       
    timer = window.clearInterval(timer);   
    currentStep = 0;
  }
}
```

Thanks to the solution of sabithpocker I succeeded to create the following code that works fine and keeps me independent of trailers length:

```
var timeFrames = {};
var currentWork = trailer[0];
var time = 0;

for ( var i = 1; i < trailer.length; i++ ) {    
  var previousWork = trailer[i-1];  
  var currentWork = trailer[i]; 
  var addTime = works[previousWork]['time'];
  time = time + addTime;
  timeFrames[time] = currentWork;
};
```

Comment: Please include the actual `setInterval()`(s) to your post.

Comment: Hope this is what you meant: timer = window.setInterval( intervalTimer, stepSize );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timeFrames = {}; 

timeFrames[tty_1] = trailer[1]; //timeFrames["140"] = trailer[1]
```

the other way, you will get

```
timeFrames = {tty_1 : "value of trailer[1]"}
```

Final code posted by OP in comments:

```
var first = trailer[0];
var second = trailer[1];
var third = trailer[2];
var fourth = trailer[3];
var timeFirst = works[first]['time'];
var timeSecond = timeFirst + works[second]['time'];
var timeThird = timeSecond + works[third]['time'];
var timeMax = timeThird + 90; //automatic trailer show timer //time line trailer fades 
var timeFrames = {};
timeFrames[timeFirst] = second;
timeFrames[timeSecond] = third;
timeFrames[timeThird] = fourth;
var maxStep = timeMax;
```

Comment: Very fine! Than you both! So I did: var first = trailer[0];
var second = trailer[1];
var third = trailer[2];
var fourth = trailer[3];

var timeFirst = works[first]['time'];
var timeSecond = timeFirst + works[second]['time'];
var timeThird = timeSecond + works[third]['time'];
var timeMax = timeThird + 90;
//automatic trailer show timer
//time line trailer fades
var timeFrames = {}; 
timeFrames[timeFirst] = second;
timeFrames[timeSecond] = third;
timeFrames[timeThird] = fourth;

var maxStep = timeMax; And it is what I wanted to achieve.